# Making Commas appear at the top instead of bottom

Tags: fonts, symbols

How would one make a symbol, say `\circ` in a symbol separated set of letters i.e. `A_{\circ} B` appear at the top between the letters i.e. `A^{\circ} B`, but to an arbitrary height (not just using _ or ^)?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the difference between a comma at the top and an apostrophe?

Comment: @Bernard That's what I was wondering. Is the concern with searching, perhaps? (But why not use an apostrophe anyway, since that is what it will look like?)

Comment: Its name is `typographical apostrophe` and it corresponds to unicode U2019. Can't you have it on your keyboard? With UTF8 input encoding, it would be very simple.

Comment: I some font families -- including Computer Modern -- the apostrophe character is identical to a raised comma character. In other font families, the two characters can look quite different from each other. Even within the Computer Modern family, when using `\ttfamily` the `,` (comma) and `'` (apostrophe) characters don't look at all the same.

Comment: @Bernard U+2019 is RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK.

Comment: @egreg: I've checked in [Apostrophe (typographie)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe_(typographie)) and found this: `Unicode recommande l’utilisation du guillemet-apostrophe (U+2019) pour représenter l’apostrophe`. So???

Comment: You should rephrase also the title...

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\raisedcirc}[1][0ex]{%
    \mathrel{\raisebox{#1}{$_\circ$}}%
}

\begin{document}
$A_{\circ} B$ 

$A{\raisedcirc[0.1ex]} B$
$A{\raisedcirc[0.5ex]} B$
$A{\raisedcirc[1ex]} B$
$A{\raisedcirc[1.5ex]} B$
$A{\raisedcirc[2ex]} B$
$A{\raisedcirc[2.5ex]} B$ 
$A{\raisedcirc[-0.1ex]} B$
$A{\raisedcirc[-0.3ex]} B$
$A{\raisedcirc[-0.5ex]} B$
$A{\raisedcirc[-0.7ex]} B$
$A{\raisedcirc[-0.9ex]} B$
$A{\raisedcirc[-1.1ex]} B$
\end{document}
```

[image]